# How to override normal Wordpress search in Buddypress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, buddypress, search

hi
i have wordpress and buddypress installed and i wanted to be able to search through forum posts, blog posts and other info all over the site.

i found [Search Engine (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-engine/) and installed it.
after a brief indexing process i was able to perform all of my search requests but the problem is that when this plugin is enabled and i try to search for something inside the wp-admin, there are no results. when i turn the plguin off the wp-admin search runs.
i also tried google search plugin but the outcome was the same.
how can i keep my search plugin and the normal plugin work together?
thanks

Comment: This plugin is marked as "beta version currently in development", I wouldn't use it on live site and it probably makes little sense to try fixing it or anything before release. Send your feedback to developer so he is aware of issue.

Comment: thanks, so is there another plugin that i can use? we want a plugin that will search thourgh all of the blogs, forum messages and everything and show the search results combined.

Comment: if you want to exclude admin area search functions from the plugin's scope, the answer is probably just adding a conditional `if (!is_admin())` at the proper point in the plugin's source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it by using this tutorial: [Creating The sitewide global/unified search Page for your Buddypress Theme](http://buddydev.com/buddypress/creating-the-sitewide-globalunified-search-page-for-your-buddypress-theme/) (28 Apr 2010; Buddy Dev)