# plugin to search entire posts, blogs, forum, users

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, search, buddypress

hi
can anyone recommend a good search engine plugin that allows the users to search for posts, blogs, forums, users, etc and shows the results as a combined result and not divided into categories?
we need a good plugin in our site that will not override the normal wordpress search.
we're using wordpress and buddypress.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [search engine plugin overrides the normal wordpress search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/search-engine-plugin-overrides-the-normal-wordpress-search)

Comment: It is not a duplicated question because one of the posts refers to a problem with the plugin and this posts refers to all of the plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this Premium Plugin can help you:

http://codecanyon.net/item/relevant-search-wordpress-plugin/121503

Comment: thanks but this plugin isnt free. do you know any free plugin that can do the same trick?

Comment: Its 14$ ... thats free if you consider the value you will get. Sorry don't know any free ones.