# a better search?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, search

hi
how to create advanced search with out plugin, create with form 
    * Support for "+" (must have) and "-" (must not have)
    * Search title, content, excerpt, taxonomies or comments (or any combination thereof)
    * Search within a date
    * Search for at least one word in phrase
    * Search exact phrase
    * Search for combinations of exact phrase and any words

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Custom Search - the following links show you how to do it.

http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/replace-wordpress-search-with-google-search-box

http://www.davidrisley.com/how-to-replace-your-wordpress-search-with-google/

Comment: I do not want to use Google

Comment: Why not? It seems like the easiest way of achieving this. You could also use bing custom search if you have an aversion to Google

Comment: Bing just uses the Google results. you can ...google for this

Answer (score 1):

I've asked that same question a few weeks ago and i've found the solution for this search issue.
Just go to [How to override normal Wordpress search in Buddypress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/search-engine-plugin-overrides-the-normal-wordpress-search)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/

Comment: relevanssi is very good plugin but i need more features